# Reading file of character data with while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, ifstream, getc

I have a file with data like:

1F B8 08 08 00 00 00 00

I am reading it into an int, casting it to a character, and storing it in an array.

```
int n, i = 0;
char c;
while (ifs >> std::hex >> n) {
   c = static_cast<unsigned char>(n);
   r[i++] = c;
}
```

works fine.  How do I go about doing this if there is no white space in the data, i.e.

1FB8080800000000

The above code just fills n to maxint and exits.  I can create something using getc or the like but I'd like the C++ code to handle both cases.

Comment: C++ code is perfectly capable of reading one character at a time, like `getc`. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the numbers as *strings* and use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to limit the number of characters read. Then use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert to integers:

```
std::string ns;
while (ifs >> std::setw(2) >> ns) {
    r[i++] = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(ns, nullptr, 16));
}
```

Will work with both the space-delimited and non space-delimited input.

Comment: I'm trying to use

`code` 
while (ifs >> std::setw(2) >> std::hex >> i)
`code`

where i is an integer.  Returns 0x7FFFFFFF.  I'd like to avoid all the string/casting rigamarole.  Why would that code not return a hex char?